I stole a phone
I stole someone phone when he was sleeping in a lecture hall. I don't know the person or his face. I only know his department and level. Its been 3 weeks already. I am afraid that I might be branded and label as a thief if I return it back if that is even possible. I don't know what to do.

There should be a 'lost and found' office, give it to them. Otherwise give it to the security department telling them that you found it. There is no real reason for them to suspect or label you as a thief given that they believe that you are the one returning it after finding it. If you are paranoid then send it via courier. In the future avoid stealing in the first place.
